# How should I align three buttons so that they stack horizontally in Bootstrap

Tags: jquery, html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I want to align three buttons on top of a div UI Grid so that they align horizontally equal spaces apart.

I am new to Bootstrap. So please explain what is being done also. Here is what I that I could come up with.

But they span across the entire screen and also first two align next to each other and the other one pulls to the extreme right.

```
<div class="home-grid-content" ng-controller="TransactionDetailsUnmergeController">
    <div ng-style="pleaseWait">
        <div class="refresh" style="width:100%;height:100px;">
            <h4>Please wait....</h4>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div ng-style="toggleDetails">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <div style="padding-top:10px; float: left;">
                    <input type="submit" value="Search" class="btn btn-default" style="width:100px;" id="btnSearch" name="btnSearch" ng-click="caseSearch()" />
                </div>
                <div style="padding-top:10px; float: right;">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-model="SearchRows" ng-click="AddNewSearchRow(SearchRows)">Add New Row</button>
                </div>
                <div style="padding-top:10px;" class="center-block">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-model="SearchRows" ng-click="AddNewSearchRow(SearchRows)">Approve/Reject</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <br/>

        <div>
            <h3>Unmerge Request Log</h3>
            <div ui-grid="gridOptions_RQ" ui-grid-selection class="" ui-grid-pagination ui-grid-auto-resize>
                <div class="watermark" ng-show="!gridOptions_RQ.data.length">No data available</div>
            </div>

            <div class="grid-pager">
                <uib-pagination boundary-links="true" total-items="totalItems" items-per-page="4" ng-change="pageChanged(currentPage)" ng-show="(totalItems>4) == true"
                                ng-model="currentPage" class="pagination" direction-links="false" id="HconstUnmerge_1"
                                first-text="&laquo;" last-text="&raquo;">
                </uib-pagination>
            </div>
        </div>
        <br/>

        <div>
            <h3>Unmerge Process Log</h3>
            <div ui-grid="gridOptions_PR" ui-grid-selection class="" ui-grid-pagination ui-grid-auto-resize>
                <div class="watermark" ng-show="!gridOptions_PR.data.length">No data available</div>
            </div>

            <div class="grid-pager">
                <uib-pagination boundary-links="true" total-items="totalItems" items-per-page="4" ng-change="pageChanged(currentPage)" ng-show="(totalItems>4) == true"
                                ng-model="currentPage" class="pagination" direction-links="false" id="HconstUnmerge_1"
                                first-text="&laquo;" last-text="&raquo;">
                </uib-pagination>
            </div>
            <br/>

            <div style="margin-top:8px;">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default pull-left" ng-click="backToDetailsPage()">Cancel</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

I want these three buttons from the  extreme left to align next to each other equal spaces apart.

For now it looks like

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your three buttons all have different floats.You can give them all the same styling. You can also add `padding-right: 10px;` to the styling to add a space between the buttons.

```
<div class="col-lg-12">
            <div style="padding-top:10px; padding-right:10px; float: left;">
                <input type="submit" value="Search" class="btn btn-default" style="width:100px;" id="btnSearch" name="btnSearch" ng-click="caseSearch()" />
            </div>
            <div style="padding-top:10px; padding-right:10px; float: left;">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-model="SearchRows" ng-click="AddNewSearchRow(SearchRows)">Add New Row</button>
            </div>
            <div style="padding-top:10px; padding-right:10px; float: left;" class="center-block">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-model="SearchRows" ng-click="AddNewSearchRow(SearchRows)">Approve/Reject</button>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Precious . Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

I use this usually, it should work for the bootstrap part. not sure about the angular part. This is a small code snipped from my own code. I assume you can adapt it to your needs.

```
<div class="form-group col-md-2">
     <input type='button' class='form-control btn btn-success btn-sm input-sm'></input>             
</div>
<div class="form-group col-md-2">
     <input type='button' class='form-control btn btn-success btn-sm input-sm'></input>
</div>
<div class="form-group col-md-2">
     <input type='button' class='form-control btn btn-success btn-sm input-sm'></input>
</div>
```